# Hyphenation with iText7

Tags: itext, itext7

I try to use Hyphenation in `iText7`

I used an example found here: [Hyphenation Example](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/general-questions-about-itext/itext7-how-hyphenate-text)

But it doesn't work.

In my code I tried this:

```
Dim h As New Hyphenator("de", "DE", 2, 2)
Dim s As Hyphenation = h.Hyphenate("Leistungsscheinziffer")
```

But after executing the code s is NOTHING.

When trying this code...

```
dim stringTest as String = "Hier steht der Text zur Silbentrennung mit Leistungsscheinziffer"
p = New Paragraph()
p.SetHyphenation(new HyphenationConfig("de", "DE", 2, 2))
p.Add(new Text(stringTest))
doc.Add(p)
```

...the resulting text is NOT hyphenated.

Same result (with no hyphenation) with this little change:

```
p.Add(New Text(stringTest).SetHyphenation(New HyphenationConfig("de", "DE", 1, 1)))
```

The dependencies of my application are:
[image: Dependencies / References]

I have a reference to itext.hyph.dll

And in the code there are these imports:

```
Imports iText.Kernel.Font
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf
Imports iText.Layout
Imports iText.Layout.Element
Imports iText.Layout.Properties
Imports itextColors = iText.Kernel.Colors
Imports itextColor = iText.Kernel.Colors.Color
Imports FontConstants = iText.IO.Font.Constants
Imports iText.IO.Image
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas
Imports iText.Kernel.Geom
Imports iText.Kernel.Events
Imports iText.Layout.Hyphenation
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you made sure to add a dependency on iText7.Hyphenation?

Comment: Please list the dependencies of your application

Comment: I added a screenshot (references) and some more code-snippets into my question...

Comment: I've had trouble with iText and "Shy-hyphen" before. Is it possible that iText is inserting a shy hyphen which then isn't being rendered by the client?

Comment: Try loading the hyph assembly explicitly by calling `ResourceUtil.AddToResourceSearch(@"D:\...\itext.hyph.dll");` before using and hyphenation-related functionality. Make sure to double-check the path you pass as the parameter

Comment: WOW, that made the trick! Awesome!

Could anybody explain, why it is necessary to do it like this?